# Handlebars: change view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, handlebars.js

I need to make the switch changes the page view (block layout). For example there are 2 template:

```
<template name="view1">
<div class="col-md-3">
    {{> menu1}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    {{> content}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="view2">
<div class="col-md-12">
    {{> menu2}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    {{> content}}
</div>
</template>
```

Button change template:

```
<button>View1</button>
<button>View2</button>
```

Parent template

```
{{#if isView}}
        {{> view2}}
        {{else}}
        {{> view1}}
{{/if}}
```

In project used MeteorJs and 'isView' change as

```
Template.priceplan.isView = function(){
return Session.get('isView');
}
```

The page layout changes, but disappear from the elements all styles (and others) that have been applied jQuery.
Elements in the two patterns are the same, only changing their location. How to save all?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using a router instead? Like Meteor Router.

Comment: can you clarify: you are using some jquery-based code to further change the style and some other details about the views, but those changes disappear when changing the view and that is the problem you would like to solve?

Comment: Akshat, thanks for the idea, but dont want change link.

Comment: Christian Fritz, in template {{> content}} for example used JQuery plugin(jslider), which applicable to input, but after the change of VIEW on the page is default input. And for example validated form with messeges about incorrect fields, but after change of view on display default form